# Matlab Code to solve Matrix Differential Riccati Equation with Terminal constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I  am new to the theory of MDRE and the following came up while I was going through the text by Dockener(2000)(page 181). They mention that the following coupled Riccati equations can be solved 'readily' by numerical methods. I am sure I am missing something, but i have not been able to figure out how to go about it in Matlab.

Without further ado:

> $$\dot{v}_1(t)=g_1+rv_1(t)-b_1(v_1(t))^2-c_1v_1(t)v_2(t)$$
>   $$\dot{v}_2(t)=g_2+rv_2(t)-b_2(v_2(t))^2-c_2v_1(t)v_2(t)$$
>   With boundary conditions $v_1(T)=0,v_2(T)=0$

My initial hunch was that I could use Matlab's bvp4c or bvp5c boundary value problem solving routine to solve them, but my attempt was not successful. I fear that the lack of initial condition i.e $v_i(0)$ is to the fault. (The matlab documentation seems to suggest that i need the conditions for the beginning and end of the time period).

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I have used so far.

```
function dydx = bvpfcn(x,y) % equation to solve
 dydx = zeros(2,1);
 dydx(1)=0.2-5*y(1)-0.1*(y(1)^2)-2*y(1)*y(2)
 dydx(2)=0.22-5*y(2)-0.12*(y(2)^2)-2.5*y(1)*y(2)
 end
```

The boundary conditions are here

```
function res = bcfcn(ya,yb) % boundary conditions
res = [yb(2)
    yb(1)];
end
```

The initial guess is here

```
function g = guess(x) % initial guess for y and y'
g = [x^2
    x^2];
end
```

And the final call is this

```
xmesh = linspace(0,2,5);
solinit = bvpinit(xmesh, @guess);
```

The error that I am getting is

```
Error using bvp5c (line 266)
Unable to solve the collocation equations -- a singular Jacobian encountered
```

I did try solving the the example from the documentation using only two 
   terminal conditions. And that seemed to work. I am not sure what is the missing bit here

Comment: You can use `ode45` to integrate backwards, it is only required that the time array is monotonous, the direction is free. // You should have been able to use bvp4c, can you give the code you tried and (if any) the error messages?

Comment: @LutzL I have added the code and the error that I am getting. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: I tried using ode45 and integrate backwards. Although, the solutions do not quite match, they look qualitatively the same. I think maybe the lack of good initial guess may throw off the bvp4c solver. Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you get your initial guess? Would using `x*(T-x)` or `(T-x)^2` --satisfying the boundary condition--, or the same scaled down so that the maximum has a sensible value, give a result with the BVP solvers?

Comment: Hi Lutzl. I tried these guesses. Now the solutions look are much closer.Thanks